# Windows Native GUI Event Logger

Tags: profiling

I want to run my application and have some third party app log all of the GUI events to dialogue or file.

I've moved a wxPython app from win7 to win8 and having problems where the entire system locks for five minutes everytime I scroll one of the panels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want spy++ or its equivalent, see here for a list of options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038730/i-am-looking-for-a-windows-spy-application